# ANDing and counting logical values in two arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the results of two messy index and match functions that are in the format { TRUE; FALSE; FALSE } and { TRUE; TRUE; FALSE }.

I'm trying to AND these two logical arrays together and count the TRUE values in the resulting array.

To test, I've set two cells to the values:

```
(U43)={TRUE;FALSE;FALSE}
(U44)={TRUE;TRUE;FALSE}
```

I've tried =COUNTIF(U44, TRUE) which results in '1'

I've tried =COUNT(U44) which results in '0'

I've tried =SUM(U44) which results in '0'

I've tried =PRODUCT(U44) which results in '0'

How can I AND the two arrays to get the result { TRUE; FALSE; FALSE } and count the TRUE values?  The expected result I'm trying to get at is '1' after the AND of the two arrays (i.e. Only one TRUE value in the resulting array)

Comment: Sumproduct should do just that

Comment: When I try =SUMPRODUCT(U43) I get "#VALUE!"

Can you give a specific example with SUMPRODUCT that results in the number of TRUE values in the array?

Comment: You won't get a sensible answer by putting {TRUE;FALSE;FALSE} into a cell - this just looks like a text value which is why (for example) you get a count of zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare two ranges (or arrays rather) like that you could use `SUMPRODUCT` as per my comment. An example would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT({TRUE;FALSE;FALSE}*{TRUE;TRUE;FALSE})
```

If your values happen to be text values, maybe try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(MID(U43,2,LEN(U43)-2),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")*FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(MID(U44,2,LEN(U44)-2),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

Comment: @SJR, as Tom Sharpe mentioned, OP might be using text values looking like arrays. I've edited the answer to take this into consideration (hope there are no translation mishaps in there)

Answer (score 0):

When putting an array into one cell only the first value is stored as the value of that cell.

Putting `=INDEX({TRUE,FALSE,TRUE},0)` in B2 would only return `TRUE` in B2 and as such all formula that refer to B2 will only return that one value.

If you want to include the whole array you will need to put the formula itself in the other formula:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX({TRUE,FALSE,TRUE},0)))
```

This will return `2`, where `=SUMPRODUCT(--B2)` would only return `1`.